# Android MediaPlayer plays more than once

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a problem where the android MediaPlayer randomly plays a given song more than once at the same time. I'll hear two instances of the song playing and it sounds terrible. Here is my code:

```
static MediaPlayer mp;
boolean music;
Context c;

public Music(Context c){
    this.c = c;
}

public void playSound(Context context){      
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.n);
    if(!mp.isPlaying()){
        mp.start();
    }
}

public void playMusic(){
    if(!music){
        playSound(c);
        music = true;
    }
}
```

The music file is an .mp3 file which is 4.33 long.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try mp.setLooping(false);
Also in your playsound() you are saying if music is not playing, play it again

Comment: You haven't provided enough code to determine the actual problem, but I bet you are essentially using a static `MediaPlayer` inside an `Activity`, right? That's a bad design. The `MediaPlayer` should be in a local `Service` so that it isn't tied to the `Activity` lifecycle.